# Best practice of spacing

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, line-spacing

What would be the best configuration of spacing of elements (lines, paragraphs, section titles, lists, list items, ...) in document (such as official report, thesis)?

The criteria are:

1. Perception of the document
2. Long-time reading quality
3. International standards of scientific documents

I suppose all this sizes should be proportional to the font size.

Comment: Short comment: (La/Xe/pdf/Lua)TeX does this basically all out of the box, because that are the reasons it was designed: to keep reading quality, provide means for (scientific) documents and appealing look/perception. Tuning here and there is possible...

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I use LaTeX. Spacing among the different elements are not my concern, it just works out of teh box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't normally answer only with pointers elsewhere, but you've asked a question it takes *books* to answer -- sorry.

Here are a couple of my favourites:

- Robert Bringhurst's [*The Elements of Typographic Style*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-Typographic-Style-Robert-Bringhurst/dp/0881792063)
- Jan Tschichold's [*The Form of the Book*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Form-Book-Morality-Classic-Typography/dp/0881791164/)

I'm sure other answers will help your reading list to grow.